# Creating a big netcdf file (>10Gb) with netCDF4 in python

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I am having problems trying to create a very big netCDF file in python in a machine with 8gb of RAM.

I created a very big array with numpy.memmap in order to have this array in disk and not in ram because its size exceeds the available ram and swap space. (ram and swap = 8 gb each)

I created a variable in the nc file with

```
var = ncout.createVariable('data',ARRAY.dtype,\
                       ('time','latitude','longitude',),\
                        chunksizes=(5000,61,720))

var[:]=ARRAY[:]
```

When the code reach this point It loads into the ram the ARRAY that is saved in disk and then I have memory error.

How can I save such a big files?

Thanks.

Comment: can you write the thing in slices?

Comment: You could do something like `for i in range(first_axis_length): var[i,:]=ARRAY[i,:]`

Comment: When I try this I get this error   `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>  
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 3608, in  netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__setitem__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:35775 )  
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to read and write large NetCDF4 files is with [Xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), which reads and writes data in chunks automatically using Dask below the hood.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('my_big_input_file.nc', 
            chunks={'time':5000, ,'latitude':61, ,'longitude':720})
ds.to_netcdf('my_big_output_file.nc',mode='w')
```

You can speed things up by using [parallel computing with Dask](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#parallel-computing-with-dask).

Answer (score 0):

Iterating directly over an array gives you the slices along the first dimension. Using `enumerate` will give you both the slice and the index:

```
for ind, slice in enumerate(ARRAY):
    var[ind] = slice
```

I'm not positive whether netCDF4-python will keep the slices around in memory, though.